# Separate optimizer for discriminator and the rest of the model in adversarial setting

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a model with the following components.

1. embedding layer
2. encoder
3. generator
4. discriminator
5. feed-forward neural network

I want to define two optimizers. One for the discriminator only and one for the rest. I am doing the following.

```
optimizers = []
model_params = chain(model.embedding.parameters(), model.encoder.parameters(), 
                            model.generator.parameters(), model.ffnn.parameters())
optimizers.append(optim.Adam(model_params, args.lr))
optimizers.append(optim.Adam(model.discriminator.parameters(), args.lr))
```

Is there any better way to do the same? For example, can I take the difference between `model.parameters()` and `model.discriminator.parameters()`? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, because model.parameters() returns a generator. If you want to modify a generator like you want it you have to convert it to a list anyway.